# Is there a way to move the label with the list when transferring a card to a different Trello board?

Tags: trello

When I move a card from board to board in Trello, it strips the label off. Is there a way to keep the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first to set the same Label Names in the destination board settings.
If they are the same, the labels will be kept.